# ASP.NET MVC Store temporary data in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

probably this is a simple question, but after researching a little bit, i'm still more confused than the begining because i think that my case is very particular. First said, i'm new at MVC, so, i'm still learning about .net mvc architecture.

I'll give you my use case.

I have a page that the user can perform Product Searches with possibility of about 10 to 15 filters. One query can take less than one second or more than 10 seconds, all depends of the complexity of the filters. The search is performed in a database with more than 5 million records.

After the search is finalized, the user has the option of order by several attributes, search for a specific string and so on. So, imagine that my last search take 10 seconds, it isn't a good idea make queries to database always the user wants to reorder the list of products.

For now, I'm using the Session scope to store an IEnumerable of the results returned from database. Then, if I want perform some king of filtering on returned data, I work on that list. It is really fast, and do what I want.

But I'm having some conscience problems. The Session Context doesn't seem to me the right place to temporary store that kind of information. The main reason is that I only want access to that information when I am at a specific Page (controller). If I quit that page, my goal is that information be deleted.

My question is about this, Session context is the best place to do this actions? and how can i guarantee that when i quit that Controller the information is deleted.

Hope i was clarifying.

Comment: Probably you should cache search results in Redis storage (or something like this) and set expiration timeout there (this feature is alailable from the box)

Comment: No need for Redis, ASP.NET provides caching since Day 1.

Comment: I prefer to serialize data like this into Json and store it in the form. This means it's related to the search and is volatile without any overhead, extra technology, etc. If your worried about people tampering with it you can always obfuscate/encrypt it. Or even better do the sorting client side using Javascript or bind the data using Angular or knockout. That way you don't even have to use the server to do the ordering at all

Comment: Do you need paging on the page with the search results?

Comment: FYI, this is far too broad/opinion based

Comment: thank you all for the feedback. i'll try some of the approaches and give you feedback in a few days

Answer (score 1):

Definitively Session.Context doesn't seems like a legit place to store such info.

In my projects, I usually query info on every user filter, although we have quite lesser databases, queries perform quite fast and we use AJAX calls to improve user experience.

In your environmentI'd take one of two approachs:

1) If data resultsets are easy to fit into your model classes and usually are composed of few elements:

Then you can try to pass back the resultset to the controller who manages filtered searches. Allow your business classes to filter a previous dataset or query database if it hasn't a previous resultset.

2) Data structure of resultsets is complex and modelbinder cannot directly load it back into the controller, or just resultsets have a lot of results, so passing back and forth so many results from client to server and back seems like a bad idea:

In this case I'd probably go for a client solution with javascript. I'd difference when any user makes a query to the database or just is refinning a previous query. On the first case I'd call a controller which returns a resultset, on the second one I'd create a filtering engine on client code.

To convert your resultset to a data structure that could be easily managed by javascript use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First of all 5 000 000 records its not a big deal.

1. Start with query profiling you need to add some indexes you can load queries to Sql Management studio and profile them even more SMS will also suggest you indexes.
2. Where to store cache it always depends. There is many ways you can do that. Firstly you can write your own [cache provider](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/) and store serialized objects in database then you can get it by specific key (could be sesssion id, user id), deserialize and process data. Down side is that if you are loading huge amount of data to memory it will not help even slow down the system
3. In .net there are [classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx) for caching
4. You can use [redis](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingRedisAsAServiceInAzureToSpeedUpASPNETApplications.aspx), or [memcached](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62)

Caching really depends on your setup, on your queries but again i would start from optimizing sql queries and making sure that they are using indexes